# System File Attribute

Tags: vb.net, file, attributes, system, hidden

I am trying to set an ini file as a system file but before I do this I want to make it hidden. I want to do this because I want no one to be able to see it even if they have hidden files enabled (so that they can see hidden files). But when I set the file to hidden and then set it to system it removes the hidden attribute and makes it system only. I have also tried setting it hidden manually and then setting it system via my program but it doesn't work.

The code I am using is simply just this:

```
File.SetAttributes(settingsDir, FileAttributes.Hidden)
File.SetAttributes(settingsDir, FileAttributes.System)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes dont accumulate:

```
File.SetAttributes(settingsDir, FileAttributes.Hidden)
File.SetAttributes(settingsDir, FileAttributes.System)
```

The first sets to hidden, then to system.  to do both:

```
File.SetAttributes(settingsDir, FileAttributes.Hidden OR FileAttributes.System)
```

Comment: You have to put OR rather than AND. Take a look at the example in the MSDN link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) to understand these ideas better. By default, in this kind of situations where you use bitwise operators to set a property OR is the right choice (AND implies that the given property is already present).

Comment: DOH!  you are right - I was thinking ahead on maybe giving and example for testing/reading existing attribute(s).  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed now.